# Error message when compiling Latex in Ubuntu

Tags: 15.10, latex

I'm trying to compile a Latex file in Ubuntu 15.10, but I get the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `lineno.sty' not found.
```

I googled this error and found 3 pages, all offering the same solution:

https://codeyarns.com/2014/05/14/latex-error-lineno-sty-not-found/
http://notesofaprogrammer.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/installing-linenosty-in-ubuntu-and.html
http://ask.xmodulo.com/fix-lineno-sty-not-found-latex-error-linux.html

which was to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-humanities
```

I have done this, and it seemed to work successfully, but I still get the same error message when I try to compile. I have closed and re-opened the terminal.

Comment: FYI, Ubuntu 15.10 has gone EOL for a while. Please consider upgrading to 16.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 15.10 and later you need to install the package `texlive-latex-recommended` instead of `texlive-humanities`.

On http://packages.ubuntu.com/ you can search for packages containing some file.